# Вывод товара в корзине

Tags: php

Всем привет! В свободное от работы время изучаю PHP и тренируюсь в создании инет-магазина, и вот возник вопрос: добавляю в корзину ботинок Арт.10001  размер 20 из выпадающего списка, в корзине выводится этот ботинок с размером 20; затем добавляю этот же ботинок, но с размером 24 - а в корзине уже выводится этот последний ввод с размером 24. Вот как поменять код, какой применить принцип, чтобы в корзину добавлялся ботинок одного id, но с разными выбранными размерами? У размеров своя таблица в mysql, с id. Заранее благодарен  :)

Добавление товара в корзину:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="add_to_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$product['id']?>">
    <select name="size" >
    <?PHP
    $sql="SELECT * FROM sizes WHERE `sizes`.`id_boot`='$id' ";
    echo $sql.'<br>';
    $a=mysql_query($sql);
    while ($b = mysql_fetch_array($a))
    {
          echo  "<option  value='$b[2]' >  $b[2] </option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Добавить в корзину">
    </form>
```

Это вывод в корзине:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity):
            $product = get_product($id);

            $b['size'] = $_SESSION['cart_size'][$id];

            if (!empty($_GET['size'])) {echo $_GET['size'];}
          ?>

          <tr>
              <td align="center"><?=$product['title']; ?></td>
              <td align="center">  <?=$b['size'];?> </td>
              <td align="center">  <?=number_format($product['price'],2); ?> руб</td>
              <td align="center"><input type="text" size="2" name="<?=$id; ?>" maxlength="2" value="<?=$quantity; ?>" /></td>
              <td align="center">  <?=number_format($product['price'] * $quantity ,2); ?> руб</td>
          </tr>
```

Через array мне конкретно разжевать нужно, хотя уже много литературы перечитал :( А возможно размер через проверку добавлять? Такую проверку делаю, но ничего не добавляет.... чего то в ней не хватает...:

```
 if ($product !== get_product($id)) 
  {
   echo $_GET('id');
  }
 if ($b['size'] !== $_SESSION['cart_size'][$id]) 
  {
   echo $_GET['size'];
  }
```

Comment: value="add_to_cart"    выше в форме добавления товара в корзину. 

Ругается: Notice: Undefined variable: quantity in C:\wamp\www\MyShop\views\pages\cart.php on line 33    

Это в этих строчках:

    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="2" name="<?=$id; ?>" maxlength="2" value="<?=$quantity; ?>" /></td>
       <td align="center">  <?=number_format($product['price'] * $quantity ,2); ?> руб</td>

До этого количество с ключом были здесь: 

    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity)

Comment: А также здесь: добавляет товар +1, если уже есть в корзине такой, если нет, то просто добавляет первый товар:

    function add_to_cart($id)
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]))
     {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]++;
        return true;
     }     
     
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = 1;
        return true;
    }
        return false;
    
}

Answer (score 1):

$_SESSION['cart'] ключи не делай айдишниками, а просто номер по порядку, тогда не будет перезаписи с одинаковым id

Comment: а каким образом вместо $id сделать "номер по порядку"?.......

Comment: Здесь убрал $id: "$b['size'] = $_SESSION['cart_size'][$id];" =>  "$b['size'] = $_SESSION['cart_size'];" , но ничего не поменялось......

Comment: например так: $_SESSION['cart'][] = array('id'=>1,'size'=>2);
а когда достаешь: foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $tovar) {
var_dump($tovar);
}

Comment: myvzar, допустим вот так я задал массив: $_SESSION['cart'][] = array('id'=>$id,'size'=>$size);   а вот как через foreach это достать.....? У меня же там id задаётся "$_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity", а потом через $product выводятся все параметры товара....  А без id корзина не идентифицирует конкретный товар :(

Comment: $_SESSION['cart'][] = array('id'=>$id,'size'=>$size);
А достать id можно так: 
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $tovar) { 
$id=$tovar['id']; $size=$tovar['size']; }

Comment: myvzar,кейс добавления товара получается такой: 

case('add_to_cart'):
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      $size = $_GET['size'];
      $_SESSION['cart'][] = array('id'=>$id,'size'=>$size);
      $add_item = add_to_cart($id);
      $_SESSION['total_items'] = total_items($_SESSION['cart']);
      $_SESSION['total_price'] = total_price($_SESSION['cart']);
      header('Location:index.php?view=product&id='.$id); 
   break;

Comment: А вывод товара:
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product) { $id=$product['id']; $size=$product['size']; }
   $product = get_product($id);
   $b['size'] = $_SESSION['cart_size'][$id];?>
     <tr><td align="center"><?=$product['title']; ?></td>
         <td align="center">  <?=$b['size'];?> </td>
         <td align="center">  <?=number_format($product['price'],2); ?> руб</td>
         <td align="center"><input type="text" size="2" name="<?=$id; ?>" maxlength="2" value="<?=$quantity; ?>" /></td>
         <td align="center"><?=number_format($product['price'] * $quantity ,2); ?> руб</td></tr>

Comment: Блин, здесь нет редактора, чтобы код выделять... :(
В корзине при этом выводится целая куча ошибок - ни по id товар не определяется(соответственно ни описания, ни цены) ни количества не видит..

Comment: @arhat78 четыре пробела слева форматируют код

вот так:

    hello('world'); //комментарий 

можно кусок вставить в поле ответа, там нажать форматирование и скопировать в поле коммента.

Comment: а что делает функция add_to_cart? И какие ошибки?